# 2 Sifrei Torah for close readings

Tags: minhag, torah-service, sefer-torah, four-parshiot, mishpatim

This morning we read Parashat Mishpatim (Exodus [21:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0221.htm) - [24:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0224.htm)) and the special reading of Parashat Shekalim (Exodus [30:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0230.htm#11)-16). The custom everywhere I have ever seen is to remove two Sifrei Torah from the ark for the two readings and to wrap up the first before reading from the second. This custom is very appropriate for other special second readings which are often far apart, as this saves time for the congregation instead of waiting while the scroll is rolled.

However, the readings this morning were only about 8 columns apart from each other! In my mind it is certain that rolling the scroll forward eight columns takes much less time than wrapping up the first Torah and opening the second. This is in fact our practice for the reading on a fast day, which skips from Exodus [32:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0232.htm#11) to [34:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0234.htm), a gap of approximately 2 columns, yet we only use one scroll.

Does anyone suggest using just one scroll when the second reading is this close?

I note that the same question applies to Rosh Chodesh on Parashat Chukat when the gap is from Numbers [22:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0422.htm) to [28:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0428.htm#9), also a gap of about 8 columns.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=50

Comment: Rosh Chodesh Tevet is not a bad example too.

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/894743/rabbi-yehoshua-grunstein/two-torahs-for-no-reason-/

Comment: Wait shouldn't it be Korach instead of Chukkat if Rosh Chodesh Tammuz is Shabbat? Ah it's Chukat if it's a leap year that started on Thursday because Mattot Masei is split.

Comment: https://minchasasher.com/shiur/parsha-shiurim/shekalim-chodesh/ R Shmuel Salant did this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are right. There is a Shita of the [Meiri Bais HaBechira in Megila](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30808&st=&pgnum=83) that says that on Parshas Shekalim you should only take out one Sefer Torah.

I imagine that the reason the Shulchan Aruch mentions that we use two Sefer Torahs is because of Lo Pelug.

Comment: From what I see, he only suggests it, but says the minhag is otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

[Sefer HaToda'ah (The Book of Our Heritage) says](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=CX3EFLa4dmAC&lpg=PP1&dq=book%20of%20our%20heritage&pg=PA346#v=onepage&q&f=false) that taking out multiple scrolls would seem unnecessary when the second portion is in close proximity to the first. Never-the-less, he says that the custom is to take out multiple Torahs.

Answer (score 7):

The entire point of reading Parashat Shekalim is to "announce" that Adar/Nissan are on the way, and as a reminder of the באחד באדר, משמעין על השקלים.

As the [Meiri Bais HaBechira in Megila (on the 12th line)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30808&st=&pgnum=83) says: `והוצאת הספר נותנת היכר לכל על ענין הפרשה` - Taking out [the 2nd] Sefer Torah creates an awareness for everybody about the [added] Parsha.

I.e.: Taking out 2 Sifrei Torah forces people to take note.

Those who aren't following inside a Chumash would hardly notice anything amiss if one simply rolled a few columns and read a different Maftir and Haftara.