# How are we allowed to take out two sifrei Torah?

Tags: halacha, torah-service, sefer-torah

The [Mishna in Yoma](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%96_%D7%90) says that when the Kohen Gadol used to read from the Sefer Torah on Yom Kippur, he had to read two portions: one from [Acharei Mos](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0316.htm#1) and the other from [Emor](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#26). It says that he used to read Acharei Mos, then he used to say the reading from Emor by heart.

The Rambam explains that he couldn't

1. Roll it to Emor - since it wouldn't be Kavod Hatzibur to have them stand and wait for the Kohen to roll the Sefer Torah.
2. Read from another Torah - since it could cause people to suspect the first one to be not kosher.

So the Kohen had no choice but to read a portion of the Torah by heart (which is a generally prohibited).

Nowadays, we take out two Torahs whenever there are two readings in one day. Why are we not concerned for the honor of the first one?

Comment: Those portions don't seem so [far apart](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14403/759)!

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe they had different column heights then?

Comment: More likely they had [sephardi style cases](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/2-sifrei-torah-for-close-readings#comment26508_14403).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gemara there ([70a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=70&format=pdf)) points out that there's a difference. In the kohen gadol's case, it would be one person reading from two different sifrei Torah; that would lead people to think that the first one was invalid. Where it's different people reading from different scrolls, though, it is fine. (The example the Gemara gives there - Rosh Chodesh Teves on Shabbos - involves three sifrei Torah; [Mishnah Berurah 144:18](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&pgnum=51) says that the same is true with two people and two scrolls.)

As for the underlying reason, Mishnah Berurah (:17) cites Magen Avraham that it is because calling up the next person makes it, in a sense, a new beginning of the Torah reading.