# 2 Sifrei Torah on Shabbat Rosh Hodesh - Parshat Hachodesh. Which Torah is used for which reading?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, four-parshiot

We have **only** 2 Sifrei Torah available instead of 3 for Shabbat Rosh Hodesh Parshat Hachodesh. The first Torah is already rolled to the correct weekly parsha (let's assume it's this year, so it's at Vayikra).

I am going to make a general assumption that we want to do as little *Tircha D'Tzibbur* ("congregational burdening") as possible, so we want to roll the Torah as little as we can. This is what I shall use in each of these scenarios. If my assumption is incorrect, please indicate what to do and why.

1. 2nd Torah rolled to Pinchas for Rosh Hodesh. Do Hagbah on 1st, use 2nd for Rosh Hodesh, Kaddish - do Hagbah on 2nd, re-use 1st and roll back to parshat Bo; do Hagbah again on the 1st.
2. 2nd Torah rolled to Bo (for Hachodesh). Roll 1st Torah to Pinchas, read for Rosh Hodesh - Kaddish, Hagbah on 1st; read from 2nd, Hagbah.
3. 2nd Torah rolled to parshat R'eh (it hasn't been used since Shmini Atzeret. It's about the same distance from R'eh to Pinchas as it is from Trumah to Pinchas). Hagbah on 1st. Roll 2nd to Pinchas - Kaddish; Hagbah; Re-use 1st, roll to Bo; Hagbah again on 1st.

In answering this question, you may want to refer to [this related M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/2-sifrei-torah-for-close-readings)

Comment: I was under the impression that a third Torah should be used in such a case.

Comment: @Noach They dont have a third one

Comment: @DoubleAA, I read it as "we have allotted", rather than "we possess". As such, my assumption was for the former.

Comment: Question 4: How should we roll the _s'farim_ before _Shabas_?

Comment: @msh210 - See the answer below. It seems quite obvious to me what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Rama to Orach Chaim, 669:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9008&st=&pgnum=575) says to use one Sefer Torah for the first and third readings, and the other Sefer Torah for the second reading.

> במקום שאין להם רק שני ספרי תורה, קורין בראשונה "וזאת הברכה", ובשנייה "בראשית", וחוזרים ולוקחים הראשונה לעניינו של יום; **וכן עושין כל מקום דבעינן שלושה ספרי תורה, ואין להם רק שתיים**

Comment: But what if it wasn't rolled right and it would be quicker to do 112?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I agree. I assumed that avoiding Tircha D'Tzibbur was the biggest concern in these situations, which is why we aim for 3 Sifrei Torah, in the 1st place - We don't want ANY delay, ideally. I don't quite understand Rama's thinking on this one, esp. to suggest this method in ALL situations. Tzarich Iyun.